# Working principle of delegate and datasource

Tags: ios, uitableview, delegates

Just want to know the working priciple of iOS delegate and datasource.
For example, when I call a [tableView numberOfRowsInSection] in some ViewController.

Seems that it is returning me [tableView.dataSource numberOfRowsInSection]

But how can I invoke [tableView numberOfRowsInSection] without returning [tableView.dataSource numberOfRowsInSection]?

May I know what is happening behind the code? Thank in advance.

Comment: The table view is caching the number of rows, until you use the insert/delete/reload methods to notify it that it changed.

Answer (score 0):

In iOS, delegate and dataource are implemented as delegation pattern. The different between them is about it's responsible and relationship with the delegating object. delegate is control of user interface, while data source is control of data. They all have to adopt protocol, in which defines a set of methods that act relevantly with each others.

Table View delegate and data source implemented aim to adopt one of best practice of using delegation pattern. Delegation design pattern responds sometimes as a callback function, however, in the case of table view data source and delegate, it allows you to control and customize properties and behavior of table view.

An example of that you can see is that implementing delegate and data source allows you to customize your table view properties such as number or sections, number of rows, which type of cells and it's behavior like clicks a row.